# Google Analytics - advanced search filters for search category

Tags: google-analytics

I have a problem with an advanced filter, that is supposed to recognize filtering and searching and create a proper Search category.

Urls for filtering:
*example.com/search/category:searchTerm*

Urls for searching:
*example.com/search/searchTerm*

Filter:

```
/search/(.*):(.*)$

Output to -> Constructor: Filter: $A1
```

This works fine. I see *Filter:Category* in the analytics report's Site search Category.

Now, I would like to separate search terms without ':' which means, the user put the term into the search field and didn't use the filter. Anything without ':' should be the *Search* category.

```
/search/((?!:).)*$

Output to -> Constructor: Search
```

This doesn't work, the Site search Category is not set to *Search*. Any idea where the error is? Is it even possible to have multiple filters for the same output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the Google Analytics [support page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en) about regular expression, you won't find the negative lookahead syntax. So it is not explicitly stated, but most likely you are trying to use a syntax, that is not supported in Google Analytics. If you use this same regular expression in any your Behavior > Content > All pages report as a filter, you will also get a syntax error:

[image]

So this should be the reason for your error. Regarding possible solutions, you might want to go for a specific string type, without the colon:

```
\/search\/([\w-%]*)[\?|$]
```

Please note, I have escaped the slashes, and also allowed (but not included) any parameters to be present in the string. Working example: https://regex101.com/r/viTcb1/2

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of a negative pattern not working. I tested it with regex101 and all fine. Let me try your proposal